# How do I select multiple items in the outliner or file browser without selecting all the items in between?

Tags: interface, outliner, file-browser, select

When I try to append multiple files at once, or when I try to select multiple objects in the outliner window that aren't right on top of each other, every file or object between the ones I select are selected as well, and there is no way to un-select them and choose the files I want.

To combat this, I've been using the drag and drop feature when I can, and other times, I append or select the objects one by one or in the viewport. Sometimes, in the outliner, I can make collections invisible, but that doesn't work if I have multiple items in multiple collections. It's annoying because I've always been able to just select whatever I needed and get it done in every other version of blender except this one, and turning on an old laptop to work on some blender files lately in v2.69 reminded me of just how much many new minor changes in 2.81 have slowed down my workflow.

Is there any way to change this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't selecting several non-continous items in Outliner and File Browser done with Shift+clicking on the items one by one? Box Select will select everything box covers as always

Comment: Outliner and File browser is Ctrl + Click

Comment: Right, this behaviour was changed [as of 2.81](https://developer.blender.org/T62971) I think and Ctrl together with Shift now work according to other existing file browsers out there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to Select the different Objects with<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>.

Try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the different Objects to select multiple Objects.

Comment: Ctrl+Click worked. Thank you Mr Zak, Emir, Ray Mairlot, susu and pr1mus. You have all been a huge help.